# Choosing NoSQL Database for Application with heavy DateRange Reports

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, hbase, couchdb, nosql

I have an application in which features of the application used by any user gets continuously logged into a text file and then later (off peak hours) a scheduled application inserts these log records into MS SQL Server based RDBMS. As you can guess, this generate quite a lot of data (since single user session would generates many records and there are hundreds of users using the application concurrently all day long). The database currently has millions of records and is mainly used to generate date range based reports which gives an aggregate of which feature was used how many times for a given date range which is where the database is giving performance issues.

Now I am aware that straight forward solution to this would be to fix the Database design (if at all its possible!) to improve performance. But I am not supposed to suggest any SQL design changes. I am supposed to evaluate NoSQL databases with a data set similar to the one I explained above.

I start looking into NoSQL databases and I am bombarded with different types of NoSQL databases. With my initial study, I am pretty sure I can rule out Graph Oriented databases. Key-Value stores also seem inappropriate for my purpose as it will mostly allow me to query with only key as per whatever I understood from [this](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html) paper on DynamoDB. Although the requirement is heavy queries on Date Range, option of querying by features is desirable.

That leaves me with Document Oriented databases and [column family stores](http://dbmsmusings.blogspot.in/2010/03/distinguishing-two-major-types-of_29.html)

So based on all these points, which database would you suggest for my case?

**PS:** *Please do not suggest any cloud based solutions as I am not supposed to migrate data out on cloud!!!*

Comment: Have you looked into MongoDB? It's document based. The query system is a bit weird, but I think it's a right fit for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, I am looking into MongoDB, CouchDB and have to decide if a column-family store fits my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything supporting efficient range scans or partition scans will work fine for your use case.

This includes MongoDB, Cassandra, HBase, any RDBMS (especially the ones supporting partitioning). I would exclude CouchDB here, since I don't think Javascript map/reduce can compete with NoSQL/RDBMS engines implemented in C/C++/Java.

Column family stores are commonly used to work with time series. For instance, have a look at the [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/) project, based on HBase.

Finally, you may also consider to just use a search engine instead of a NoSQL store or a RDBMS. Increasingly, search engines (such as Lucene) are used for analytic workloads. For instance, have a look at the [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/), [Logstash](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/logstash/), [Kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/) triplet.

Comment: Didier, I think you may misunderstand how CouchDB and Couchbase create Map/Reduce views. They use Javascript to do the map and reduce to create a B+ tree index that is as fast as anyone else's B+ tree. Javascript is not involved at query time. Hence, I think your advice to exclude Couch-derived technologies is unwarranted by the facts. Andrew

Comment: Well, what you describe is my understanding as well - still, Javascript code is interpreted when the index is modified, which may happen at query time if the view is not up-to-date. CouchDB is a fine project, but I would not use it to for DIRT analytical workload. IMO, the other solutions will be easier (and probably faster).

Comment: JS views are capable of saturation IO, so no need to worry there. In addition, for cases where that isn’t true, you can write Erlang instead of JS and get another set of performance benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Redis](http://redis.io/) and [SSDB](https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb), the built-in data type `zset` is the ideal data type to store time based data. One the sequence is stored(insert and delete at any time), you can find by time stamp.

Here is some code snipets:

```
$ssdb->zset('z', 'a', 1384423054);
$ssdb->zset('z', 'b', 1384423055);
$ssdb->zset('z', 'c', 1384423056);
$items = $ssdb->zrange('z', 1384423054, 1384423057, $limit=100);
```

The difference between these two databases is that Redis is memory only(disk for backup), but SSDB is disk based and uses memory as cache.

Comment: and ssdb is just as fast, with 100x less memory, and built-in compression.... so really there's no reason not to use ssdb.   i'm kicking myself for not finding it sooner!